# What is this strange text in byobu's status bar?

Tags: byobu

The following appears as status bar in my byobu view:

@  9.3 〣_1-17739 0:bash* 1:bash-                                                                                ▴420kb ▾193kb 3h20m 0.28 4x2.4GHz 11.7G19% user@hostname 2018-01-21 17:07:01

what is "〣_1-17739" supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug, either in byobu or one of its backends. I've seen someone complaining about this on Twitter assuming it's probably a tmux bug. Here's a bug report from Debian distro: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892489